# How can I correctly escape string for awk input using Java?

Tags: java, string, unix, awk

I'm trying to execute the following command (which works on the terminal) within Java:

```
awk -F';' 'NR>1{gsub(/; +/,";",$0);printf("{msisdn:\"%s\",imei:\"%s\",brand:\"%s\",model:\"%s\",sap:\"%s\",sap_cod:\"%s\",file_name:\"teste\",company:{\"$ref\":\"company\",\"$id\":ObjectId\"456\")}}\n",$2,$15,$16,$17,$18,$20)}' /Users/milena/Desktop/giant.csv
```

The Java code I am using is this:

```
String fileName = "test";
String company = "456";

String awk = "awk -F';' 'NR>1";
String gsub = "{gsub(/; +/,\";\",$0);";

String printf = "printf(\"{msisdn:\\\"%s\\\",imei:\\\"%s\\\",brand:\\\"%s\\\","
            + "model:\\\"%s\\\",sap:\\\"%s\\\",sap_cod:\\\"%s\\\",file_name:\\\""+fileName+"\\\",company:"
            + "{\\\"$ref\\\":\\\"company\\\",\\\"$id\\\":ObjectId\\\""+company+"\\\")}}\\n\",$2,$15,$16,$17,$18,$20)}\' ";

String path = "/Users/milena/Desktop/giant.csv";

String command = awk + gsub + printf  + path; 

Process p
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

The error I am getting is:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
    context is
     >>> ' <<< 
    missing }
    missing )
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think, Either ending of single quote some where missing  or code Process P ... is not wrap up by try..catch... so could you please do it then let me know if still having any issue or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)`, it takes the string and breaks it into a command and arguments based on spaces.

This simple parsing is not the same as the parsing done by the shell when you invoke the command. The shell, for example, takes quotes into consideration. This means that if you have a command line like:

```
cmd 'abc' 'def'
```

The arguments that the shell will send to the `cmd` command are going to be `abc` and `def`. But if you give the same command to `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)`, it will send `'abc'` and `'def'` to `cmd` as arguments. Yes, **including the quotes!**

The situation gets worse if you have spaces in any of the arguments. If the shell gets

```
cmd 'my single argument'
```

It will invoke the command with a single argument `my single argument`. But `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` will invoke `cmd` with three arguments: `'my`, `single` and `argument'`!

So it's not recommended to use this particular overload for anything but very simple commands. Instead, you should use the overload that accepts an array of strings. The first element should be the command name, and each argument should be in a separate element:

```
String[] command = { "awk",
                     "-F;",
                     "NR>1{gsub(/; +/,\";\",$0);printf(\"{msisdn:\\\"%s\\\",...",
                     "/Users/milena/Desktop/giant.csv"
                   };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

---

Note: It is recommended to use the [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class to build a `Process` rather than `Runtime.getRuntime.exec` - it gives you better control of the command and you can pass the separate arguments right to the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I'll take a look at ProcessBuilder soon. However, when I tried calling the command with the string array it apparently enters in a infinite loop. Any idea why? It gives me no error.

Comment: @MilenaAraujo It's an awk program - does it have any output? Are you reading the output? If you don't, then the process may be blocked waiting for Java to read its output. If you want the output to go to the console, you'll have to use `ProcessBuilder`. If you want to process it in Java, you should be reading the output stream of the `Process`.

Comment: I'm reading the output using a while loop through ```BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); ``` It does have an output (it's converting from csv to json).

Comment: So, if there is output, how do you detect it's in an infinite loop? What happens after it finishes the last line in the file? Are you also checking the standard error stream? Perhaps you should open a new question for this and provide all the relevant code (preferably an [mcve]) as well as a sample input file,

Comment: I used the ProcessBuilder as you suggested and now everything works fine, as expected! Thank you again :)